# vue.js disable max-len within <template> with eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: vue.js, eslint-plugin-vue

How can I disable the max-len warnings globally within the
 `<template> </template>` tags in the .vue files?

The reason I want to do this is I don't want to write 
`<!-- eslint-disable max-len -->`
each time.

I also don't want to disable it globally for the whole vue file, so I still want to get a warning within the script tag.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no way to do that. Check this [thread](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/260).

What you can do is use

```
<!-- eslint-disable --> <!-- eslint-enable -->
```

inside every template you want to disable.